# How to fix macOS compiler errors and warnings (Catalina)

Tags: c++, c, macos, makefile, compiler-errors

I updated my macOS and xcode to latest version just 2 days ago and I got a headache due to huge number of compile errors it shows for all different softwares.

I use ./configure && make && make install commands to compile and install.

Most of errors/warnings are because of missing a nullability type specifier warnings, but at the end it fails with errors. For example `make` command for PHP 7.4.5 generates 696266 lines of warnings and errors, here is the last 266 lines:

```
/usr/local/include/signal.h:83:41: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     pthread_sigmask(int, const sigset_t *, sigset_t *) __DARWIN_ALIAS(pthread_sigmask);
                                            ^
                                             _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:83:41: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     pthread_sigmask(int, const sigset_t *, sigset_t *) __DARWIN_ALIAS(pthread_sigmask);
                                            ^
                                             _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:83:53: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     pthread_sigmask(int, const sigset_t *, sigset_t *) __DARWIN_ALIAS(pthread_sigmask);
                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:83:53: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     pthread_sigmask(int, const sigset_t *, sigset_t *) __DARWIN_ALIAS(pthread_sigmask);
                                                        ^
                                                         _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:83:53: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     pthread_sigmask(int, const sigset_t *, sigset_t *) __DARWIN_ALIAS(pthread_sigmask);
                                                        ^
                                                         _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:84:43: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigaction(int, const struct sigaction * __restrict,
                                              ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:84:43: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigaction(int, const struct sigaction * __restrict,
                                              ^
                                                _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:84:43: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigaction(int, const struct sigaction * __restrict,
                                              ^
                                                _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:85:23: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
            struct sigaction * __restrict);
                             ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:85:23: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
            struct sigaction * __restrict);
                             ^
                               _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:85:23: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
            struct sigaction * __restrict);
                             ^
                               _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:86:24: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigaddset(sigset_t *, int);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:86:24: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigaddset(sigset_t *, int);
                           ^
                            _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:86:24: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigaddset(sigset_t *, int);
                           ^
                            _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:87:31: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigaltstack(const stack_t * __restrict, stack_t * __restrict)  __DARWIN_ALIAS(sigaltstack) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
                                  ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:87:31: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigaltstack(const stack_t * __restrict, stack_t * __restrict)  __DARWIN_ALIAS(sigaltstack) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
                                  ^
                                    _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:87:31: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigaltstack(const stack_t * __restrict, stack_t * __restrict)  __DARWIN_ALIAS(sigaltstack) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
                                  ^
                                    _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:87:53: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigaltstack(const stack_t * __restrict, stack_t * __restrict)  __DARWIN_ALIAS(sigaltstack) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:87:53: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigaltstack(const stack_t * __restrict, stack_t * __restrict)  __DARWIN_ALIAS(sigaltstack) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
                                                        ^
                                                          _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:87:53: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigaltstack(const stack_t * __restrict, stack_t * __restrict)  __DARWIN_ALIAS(sigaltstack) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
                                                        ^
                                                          _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:88:24: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigdelset(sigset_t *, int);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:88:24: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigdelset(sigset_t *, int);
                           ^
                            _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:88:24: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigdelset(sigset_t *, int);
                           ^
                            _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:89:26: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigemptyset(sigset_t *);
                             ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:89:26: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigemptyset(sigset_t *);
                             ^
                              _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:89:26: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigemptyset(sigset_t *);
                             ^
                              _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:90:25: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigfillset(sigset_t *);
                            ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:90:25: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigfillset(sigset_t *);
                            ^
                             _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:90:25: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigfillset(sigset_t *);
                            ^
                             _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:94:32: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigismember(const sigset_t *, int);
                                   ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:94:32: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigismember(const sigset_t *, int);
                                   ^
                                    _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:94:32: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigismember(const sigset_t *, int);
                                   ^
                                    _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:96:25: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigpending(sigset_t *);
                            ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:96:25: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigpending(sigset_t *);
                            ^
                             _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:96:25: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigpending(sigset_t *);
                            ^
                             _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:97:37: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigprocmask(int, const sigset_t * __restrict, sigset_t * __restrict);
                                        ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:97:37: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigprocmask(int, const sigset_t * __restrict, sigset_t * __restrict);
                                        ^
                                          _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:97:37: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigprocmask(int, const sigset_t * __restrict, sigset_t * __restrict);
                                        ^
                                          _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:97:60: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigprocmask(int, const sigset_t * __restrict, sigset_t * __restrict);
                                                               ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:97:60: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigprocmask(int, const sigset_t * __restrict, sigset_t * __restrict);
                                                               ^
                                                                 _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:97:60: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigprocmask(int, const sigset_t * __restrict, sigset_t * __restrict);
                                                               ^
                                                                 _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:100:31: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigsuspend(const sigset_t *) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigsuspend);
                                  ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:100:31: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigsuspend(const sigset_t *) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigsuspend);
                                  ^
                                   _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:100:31: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigsuspend(const sigset_t *) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigsuspend);
                                  ^
                                   _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:101:28: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigwait(const sigset_t * __restrict, int * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigwait);
                               ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:101:28: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigwait(const sigset_t * __restrict, int * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigwait);
                               ^
                                 _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:101:28: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigwait(const sigset_t * __restrict, int * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigwait);
                               ^
                                 _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:101:46: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigwait(const sigset_t * __restrict, int * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigwait);
                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:101:46: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigwait(const sigset_t * __restrict, int * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigwait);
                                                 ^
                                                   _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:101:46: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigwait(const sigset_t * __restrict, int * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(sigwait);
                                                 ^
                                                   _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:103:39: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
void    psignal(unsigned int, const char *);
                                         ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:103:39: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
void    psignal(unsigned int, const char *);
                                         ^
                                          _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:103:39: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
void    psignal(unsigned int, const char *);
                                         ^
                                          _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:106:31: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigvec(int, struct sigvec *, struct sigvec *);
                                  ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:106:31: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigvec(int, struct sigvec *, struct sigvec *);
                                  ^
                                   _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:106:31: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigvec(int, struct sigvec *, struct sigvec *);
                                  ^
                                   _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/signal.h:106:48: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int     sigvec(int, struct sigvec *, struct sigvec *);
                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/signal.h:106:48: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int     sigvec(int, struct sigvec *, struct sigvec *);
                                                   ^
                                                    _Nullable
/usr/local/include/signal.h:106:48: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
int     sigvec(int, struct sigvec *, struct sigvec *);
                                                   ^
                                                    _Nonnull
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/ext/intl/intl_convertcpp.cpp:22:
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/main/php.h:33:
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/Zend/zend.h:356:
/tmp/php-7.4.5/Zend/zend_operators.h:110:18: error: expected unqualified-id
        if (UNEXPECTED(!zend_finite(d)) || UNEXPECTED(zend_isnan(d))) {
                        ^
/tmp/php-7.4.5/main/php_config.h:2333:26: note: expanded from macro 'zend_finite'
#define zend_finite std::isfinite
                         ^
/usr/local/include/math.h:155:5: note: expanded from macro 'isfinite'
    ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isfinitef((float)(x))       \
    ^
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/ext/intl/intl_convertcpp.cpp:22:
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/main/php.h:33:
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/Zend/zend.h:356:
/tmp/php-7.4.5/Zend/zend_operators.h:110:48: error: expected unqualified-id
        if (UNEXPECTED(!zend_finite(d)) || UNEXPECTED(zend_isnan(d))) {
                                                      ^
/tmp/php-7.4.5/main/php_config.h:2331:25: note: expanded from macro 'zend_isnan'
#define zend_isnan std::isnan
                        ^
/usr/local/include/math.h:165:5: note: expanded from macro 'isnan'
    ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isnanf((float)(x))          \
    ^
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/ext/intl/intl_convertcpp.cpp:22:
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/main/php.h:33:
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/Zend/zend.h:356:
/tmp/php-7.4.5/Zend/zend_operators.h:121:18: error: expected unqualified-id
        if (UNEXPECTED(!zend_finite(d)) || UNEXPECTED(zend_isnan(d))) {
                        ^
/tmp/php-7.4.5/main/php_config.h:2333:26: note: expanded from macro 'zend_finite'
#define zend_finite std::isfinite
                         ^
/usr/local/include/math.h:155:5: note: expanded from macro 'isfinite'
    ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isfinitef((float)(x))       \
    ^
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/ext/intl/intl_convertcpp.cpp:22:
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/main/php.h:33:
In file included from /tmp/php-7.4.5/Zend/zend.h:356:
/tmp/php-7.4.5/Zend/zend_operators.h:121:48: error: expected unqualified-id
        if (UNEXPECTED(!zend_finite(d)) || UNEXPECTED(zend_isnan(d))) {
                                                      ^
/tmp/php-7.4.5/main/php_config.h:2331:25: note: expanded from macro 'zend_isnan'
#define zend_isnan std::isnan
                        ^
/usr/local/include/math.h:165:5: note: expanded from macro 'isnan'
    ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isnanf((float)(x))          \
    ^
26 warnings and 17 errors generated.
make: *** [ext/intl/intl_convertcpp.lo] Error 1
```

I'm a PHP developer and I'm a `./configure && make && make install` noob. I appreciate anyone who can help.

Comment: Why are you declining use Homebrew? `brew install php@7.4`.

Comment: @S.M. Because: 1. I need to compile PHP (and some other softwares) with custom configure options, 2. Homebrew doesn't allow custom configure options anymore, 3. not all softwares I need exists in Homebrew, 4. Homebrew's --build-from-source shows same errors as above and fails compiling softwares, 5. I don't trust downloading sources or installing compiled packages from unknown/3rd party sources and 6. my question is about how to fix compile issues in Catalina, not how to install some pre-built packages.

Comment: Make sure it includes <cmath> and not <math.h> in the C++ files. There is a good chance that while `isnan` is defined as macro in <math.h> (which breaks when used as `std::isnan`), it is defined as an (overloaded) function in <cmath>.

Comment: @numzero, Thank you for the response. Should I open thousands of cpp files and fix them one by one? Or is there another way I'm not aware of? Also, "missing a nullability type specifier" warnings mostly come from stdio.h, _stdio.h, stdlib.h, _stdlib.h signal.h as well as math.h (when making php)

Comment: Use the “replace in files” facility of your favorite IDE (it may even be PHP IDE, language support doesn’t matter). Alternatively, it is possible to use `find` and `sed` as a global search-and-replace tool, like `find -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i 's/<math\.h>/<cmath>/' \;` (not guaranteed; read the docs first).

Comment: On nullability, ignore it. Warning are for those who write the code; but you don’t write `signal.h`.

Comment: Also, is it OK that system headers are in `/usr/local/include`? On most systems they are in `/usr/include` (not sure of macs, though).